# Disallow orientation in a certain CCLayer only

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, screen-orientation, cclayer

Globally my game supports two orientations: landscape right and landscape left

In one subscreen (inheriting CCLayer) I need to lock the current orientation so that ... the current orientation is locked...
When the user pops back to another screen (CCLayer), orientation should work freely again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it like this:

Edit AppDelegate.h, add a mask for locking orientation:

```
@interface MyNavigationController : UINavigationController <CCDirectorDelegate>
@property UIInterfaceOrientationMask lockedToOrientation;
@end
```

In AppDelegate.m, synthesize the mask, and replace two functions:

```
@synthesize lockedToOrientation; // assign

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if (!self.lockedToOrientation) {
        // iPhone only
        if( [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone )
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;

        // iPad only
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }
    else {
        return self.lockedToOrientation;
    }
}

// Supported orientations. Customize it for your own needs
// Only valid on iOS 4 / 5. NOT VALID for iOS 6.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (!self.lockedToOrientation) {
        // iPhone only
        if( [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone )
            return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);

        // iPad only
        // iPhone only
        return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
    }
    else {
        // I don't need to change this at this point
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Then whenever I need to lock interface to a certain orientation, I access navController in the appdelegate. Check its interfaceOrientation property and set locked mask accordingly

```
AppController* appdelegate = (AppController*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
const UIDeviceOrientation ORIENTATION = appdelegate.navController.interfaceOrientation;
appdelegate.navController.lockedToOrientation = ORIENTATION == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ? UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft : UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
```

In dealloc or whenever I wanna remove the lock, I do this:

```
    AppController* appdelegate = (AppController*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    appdelegate.navController.lockedToOrientation = 0;
```